# how to pass parameters in cakephp login action?

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'blogin');
```

Here I need to pass one parameter on blogin page, how to pass it?

Comment: $url =  array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'blogin');       $this->Auth->loginAction = array_merge($url, $my_params); Try this.

Comment: Thanks for thw quick reply, yes I tried this and its working but main thing is "$my_params" are the params of my previous page, so how to get them? like "pools/my_pool", which requires authentication, so i need "my_pool" param so user will be redirect to pools/my_pool page after login. In short I need something Take user back to previous page after logging in

Comment: Add $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); within  if ($this->Auth->login()) { block.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cartina, it worked like a charm (:, I did put it in my redirection function and now its redirecting me to previous page. thanks!

Comment: you can simply done by $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'blogin','param1');

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
$url = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'blogin'); $this->Auth->loginAction = array_merge($url, $my_params);
```

Add `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());` within `if ($this->Auth->login()) { block`